# Apply php/MySql while loop in javascript object

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, while-loop, javascript-objects

I would like to take the following php/mysql loop, and apply the results: $test,$test1,$test2 to the var Data object in the javascript code. This will make the var Data dynamic, pulling its data to construct the object form the database.

Comment: Collect all row values (`$res1`) into an array, and output it with `var treeData = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;`. And please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Ok, I will check it out, forgive me but I am very novice. Also, I am not sure how I am suppose to Collect all row values ($res1) into an array, as you said. How is that done? And what is $rows, where did you derive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
include("regDBConnect.php");

// collect all the results
$rows = array();

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Phase where Pid = 1", $db) or die("cannot select");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $rows []= array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'parent' => $row['parent'],
    'name' => $row['name'],
  );

  /*
     if you remove the line above and uncomment this instead,
     javascript objects will see all the properties you selected from the DB 
   */
  // $rows []= $row;
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
// now output the collected results
var treeData = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
</script>
```

Note that what I said about PDO/MySQLi still applies, this is just a minimal example to answer this specific question. (And in general, you should SELECT only those columns you will need, not `*`.)

Comment: Thanks soo much. It worked like a charm :) And I will start learning to code using the PDO or MySQLi.