# Running a PHP Mysql query loop in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to make my javascript menu dynamic by pulling existing pages from my mysql database.

I want to do this:
[Apply php/MySql while loop in javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531993/apply-php-mysql-while-loop-in-javascript-object) -
But in a .js file.

```
anylinkmenu4.items=[

[" echo looped content here   ", "echo looped content here.php"] ]
```

If the question above answers the question please let me know because I haven't been able to run php in a .js file.

Comment: Serve a `.php` JavaScript file instead of a `.js` file, or serve it inline, or use Ajax.

Comment: Thank you minitech.  I was able to produce the desired result by changing the .js file to a .php file and echoing the entire js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serve a .php JavaScript file instead of a .js file, or serve it inline, or use Ajax.

Thanks to minitech for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Call the php file with ajax.  See. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

See [Using jQuery, JSON and AJAX to populate a drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564333/using-jquery-json-and-ajax-to-populate-a-drop-down)

Comment: I'm sure this is useful but it didn't provide me with the answer I was looking for.